# Making a 960px wide site mobile friendly

Tags: html, css, mobile, seo, viewport

I am updating a website so that it will meet Google Mobile Friendlyness requirements. The website has been designed to a fixed width of 960px so if I set viewport to `width=960, initial-scale=1`
then [Mobile Friendly Checker extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mobile-friendly-checker/gmfflfmdcdecdonfogdofmomfhiabaeg?hl=en) reports the following problems:

**Score: 61**

- Viewport Configuration 10
- Font Legibility 40
- Size and Proximity of Links 18

If I set viewport to `width=device-width, initial-scale=1` then the website flows outside of the viewport and I get the following errors:

**Score: 64**

- Content To Viewport 50
- Size and Proximity of Links 7

In order for Google to verify as mobile friendly will I need to go down the `width=device-width, initial-scale=1` route and update the styles accordingly? Is there any other workaround?

Comment: I've hardly ever seen a desktop website that would do well on a smartphone, so i'd recommened you to make it responsive. Maybe you wanna read this post from Google-Devlopers:
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/?hl=en

Comment: We thought we might be able to implement a temporary fix before reworking the site to be responsive.

Comment: Then I would go with the `width=960, initial-scale=1`, so you can see all of the content and rebuild the site asap

Comment: Problem with `width=960, initial-scale=1` is that it fails the test.

Comment: Yes, but for now it's the best option. If your site just isn't mobile-friendly, what do you want to do? Best option: rebuild it. And in the meantime? Create the best possible experience for you mobile user. This experience might not be good, but it's currently the best possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to *trick* Google for the benefit of your rankings then you should be prepared to be 'punished' by Google for it. This will fast become the same as the back links issue where sites drop out of the ranks altogether because of dodgy practices. So, **don't do it!**

Perhaps your temp fix should include adding new classes to your css to reshape [/hack] what ever is going out of the viewport area, e.g.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
   .rightsidebar {float: none; clear: left;}
}
```